# ios triggering segue via uialertview

Tags: ios, uialertview, segue

I'm developing an iOS app and I'm somewhat stuck in trying to implement an UIAlertView that pops out when you press a button AND that triggers a segue when you press the "OK" option in the UIAlertView.

My Segue goes BACK to the previous screen, it doesn't open up a new screen.

I'll post a bit of my code so you can see how I've laid out the matter:

```
-(void)buyProduct{

 BOOL succeed = [json objectForKey:@"succeed"];


        if(succeed){
           // [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        }
}

-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

    UIAlertView * alerta =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Èxit"
                                                       message:@"La compra ha finalitzat amb èxit!"
                                                      delegate:self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    NSString *string = [alerta buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([string isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }


}
```

What I'm stuck with is this: how can I tell the app that it's got to launch the UIAlertView after the "if (succeed)" condition is fulfilled? I can't use a mere [self someMethod] because the below method has variables on its definition.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you creating another `UIAlertView` object in the `clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method??

Comment: Good point. It's a leftover from a previous attempt. I'll have to change it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `popViewControllerAnimated:` on the main queue:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
});
```

Comment: The main queue? I've never had to use that insofar. And the segue must go back to the previous screen, not open up a new one. I'll update the question.

Comment: @user3082271 Ya, the reason  you need to use the Main que is because UIAlertViews are not executed on the main que but presenting ViewControllers have to be. So you use dispatch_sync on the main que so that it will be. 

Wait, so you want to dismiss the current view controller / go back to the last view controller?

Comment: Thanks for your insight but I solved it in another manner. Thank you.